# does WSO2 Identity Server support PostgreSQL?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does WSO2 Identity Server support PostgreSQL for *identity* databases?

Start-up currently fails with the following error:

> 2013-08-01 13:22:02,501] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.IdentityDBInitializer} - 
>   Error occurred while executing SQL script for creating identity
>   database java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /opt/wso2/wso2is-4.1.0/dbscripts/identity/postgresql.sql (No such file
>   or directory)

There is no `postgresql.sql` script in folder `/opt/wso2/wso2is-4.1.0/dbscripts/identity/`.

Does this mean that there's no support for PostgreSQL, or that the script file may be found somewhere else?

**UPDATE**

I created the script myself by editing the MySQL equivalent, start-up completed successfully. But could there be any issues with PostgreSQL as database?

**UPDATE 2**

Interesting enough, API Manager 1.4.0 seems to have the script in its `wso2am-1.4.0/dbscripts/apimgt` folder. However the script does not contain all the tables in the Identity Server MySQL script.

Comment: There is a positive answer now, you should consider changing your selected correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, correct answer is now changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, WSO2 IS supports PostgreSQL.

You can find the postgresql.sql script in folder [IS_HOME]/dbscripts/identity/ with the new release of IS 4.5.0.

Answer (score 3):

There is this [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-623) reported for this, which is still in open state.